Oracle Count giving different results when executing in stored procedure vs running as independent query
I'm trying to do a count on my table and then running other query if count > 0.
Right now I'm declaring the variables like this
vId NUMBER(10) := 0;

vClStat NUMBER(2) := 0;

And this is the query for doing the count; the vId is populated by another query in the stored procedure:
SELECT COUNT(CNO) 
INTO vClStat 
FROM VIEW_M
WHERE ID = vId
  AND REC <> '5' AND CL_STATUS IN ('1');

This works well when I run it independently, returning Count = 0, which is the correct value.
However, when I have this query in a stored procedure and execute the whole thing, my dbms_ouput would return Count = 1, and it will then be valid on my If Count > 0 check later.
I do have other queries inside the stored procedure as well, but when I was testing it separately, I was already using the same ID as per the one used when it was running.
And vClStat does not have its value declared anywhere else in the stored procedure so I don't think anything could be rewriting the value.
Right now I'm not too sure what else might cause this so I'm hoping anyone can provide any ideas on the cause or just maybe suggestions on what else I can check.
Just to add, I also have other queries that are also doing the same Count check in the same stored procedure. Only with different tables and variables. But none of them are having the same issue, only this one which is why it feels a bit weird to me.

Have you verified that vId is what you expect immediately before that query, and that vClStat is 1 immediately after it? Are you using the right data types?Does your view have a column called vId (maybe unlikely in this case but worth ruling out)? Are you calling the procedure and running the query standalone in the same session - if not might there be uncommitted changes affecting the result? Or at least as the same user, or definitely against the same schema?

@AlexPoole yes, I placed a dbms_output for the vId right before the query and was using that value for my test. Also checked the vClStat immediately after as well and it was returning 1 at that time. Checked my View, no vId  column. And I was already running both of them on the same session, as the same user

Did you run it standalone as the same user the procedure is owned by?

@PaulW, yes I did

@n.hanz Please setup a fiddle based on your data that allows to reproduce your issue and share the url in your question.
